# PHP & MySQL Image deletion problem?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script that deletes a user's avatar image that is stored on the filesystem. In addition, the image name is stored in a MySQL database.

But for some reason the script deletes all the user's info. For example if the users_id is 3, all of the user's info like first name, last name, age and so on, are deleted as well. Basically everything is deleted including the user.

How do I fix this so only the images and image name is deleted?

Here is the code:

```
$user_id = '3';

if (isset($_POST['delete_image'])) { 
    $a = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE avatar = '". $avatar ."' AND user_id = '". $user_id ."'";
    $r = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $a) or trigger_error("Query: $a\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if ($r == TRUE) {           
        unlink("../members/" . $user_id . "/images/" . $avatar); 
        unlink("../members/" . $user_id . "/images/thumbs/" . $avatar);

        $a = "DELETE FROM users WHERE avatar = '". $avatar ."' AND user_id = '". $user_id ."'";
        $r = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $a) or trigger_error("Query: $a\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `avatar` is an attribute of the table `users` you may want to simply set the `avatar` attribute to `NULL`. As you were doing, you were effectively deleting the entire row.

Therefore you should be using the `UPDATE` operation instead of `DELETE`:

```
$a = "UPDATE users SET avatar = NULL WHERE user_id = '". $user_id ."'";
```

In addition, be aware that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection). You should consider using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

At the minute your sql says to delete the user where the avatar=x and the user_id=y so update instead.

`$a = "UPDATE users SET avatar=NULL where user_id='". $user_id ."'";`